# How to test token transfer?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, testing

I have a program `lib.rs` that at some point make a USDC transfer from one account to another.

It works on mainnet because I put the `token_program_id` that corresponds to USDC but this `token_program_id` does not exist anymore when I test with `anchor test`.

```
        let transfer_to_store = transfer(
            token_program_id,
            source_pubkey,
            destination_pubkey,
            authority_pubkey,
            signer_pubkeys,
            amount,
        );
```

Is there a way to test with the same `token_program_id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to load account data from mainnet (or devnet etc) into your localnet every time you run `anchor test`.

##### 1. Cloning

Under the hood, anchor test uses `solana-test-validator`. This has an argument you can pass it called `--clone` whose doc string reads as follows:

```
    -c, --clone <ADDRESS>...
            Copy an account from the cluster referenced 
            by the --url argument the genesis 
            configuration. If the ledger already exists 
            then this parameter is silently ignored.
```

You can [configure your `Anchor.toml`](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/anchor-toml_reference.html#testvalidatorclone) so that on every run of `anchor test`, it effectively adds these flags to its internal `solana-test-validator`.

##### 2. Loading manually procured JSON data

Similar to what is described above, there is a `--account` argument:

```
 --account <ADDRESS FILENAME.JSON>...
            Load an account from the provided JSON file 
            (see `solana account --help` on how to dump 
            an account to file).
            Files are searched for relatively to CWD and 
            tests/fixtures. If the ledger already exists
            then this parameter is silently ignored.
```

Following the `solana account --help`, what you'd want to do to e.g. dump the USDC mint account from mainnet is:

```
$ solana -um account -o usdc_mint.json --output json EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v
```

And there's [a similar way](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/anchor-toml_reference.html#testvalidatoraccount) to configure your Anchor.toml.

##### 3. Copying Programs

You can use `solana program dump` to copy a program from mainnet into a local `.so` file. From there, it's [a simple configuration](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/anchor-toml_reference.html#genesis) to add that program to your localnet testing as well.

##### Edit: On the topic of modifying cloned account data

In a reply, OP effectively asks, "how do I modify cloned account data, for example changing an account's mint authority?"

This requires that you have some means to deserialize the data, modify it, and serialize it back into JSON data to be used with technique (2) above. This is not trivial, and the only way I've accomplished this is to [write my own crate, which I've open sourced](https://github.com/Jungle-Finance/jungle-fi-cli-utils/tree/master/localnet-tools).

In response to your reply, I added an example showing explicitly how to clone and modify the USDC mint. Here's the relevant part below:

```
    let usdc = LocalnetAccount::new_from_clone::<SplMintAccount, _>(
        &pubkey!("EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v"),
        &RpcClient::new("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com".to_string()),
        "usdc_mint.json".to_string(),
        Some(|mint: SplMintAccount| {
            let mut mint = mint.clone();
            mint.mint_authority = COption::Some(test_user.address.clone());
            SplMintAccount::from_spl_mint(mint)
        })
    ).unwrap();
```

Instead of creating entire test suites like in the example, you could write something simple that creates this `LocalnetAccount` object, and just [calls `write_to_validator_json_file` on it](https://github.com/Jungle-Finance/jungle-fi-cli-utils/blob/8c15470af2ff40e6c4c4d85799d19b597e52d0db/localnet-tools/src/localnet_account.rs#L114).

You could also use this technique to just create token accounts with arbitrary USDC balances instead of modifying the mint.

Note that the `T: AccountSerialize + AccountDeserialize` that I am using in this example is not the Anchor SPL mint directly, but my own wrapper struct (it serializes all the same). This is because Anchor SPL types [have an empty `impl AccountSerialize`](https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/src/anchor_spl/token.rs.html#395), which by default do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I still have a question. So I can add a program from the mainnet with the 3 techniques you showed me. 

In my test, I copied the USDC mint program. I would like to give some USDC to an account to test the function in my rust program that interest with USDC. I obviously do not have the mint authority so how am I supposed to test ?

Comment: See edited answer above. I'll add an example to my repo in a bit.